# Padding html input changes absolute position

Tags: html, css, position, padding, absolute

I have some absolutely positioned text input elements and I want to give them some left and right padding because it makes it easier to place the cursor at the end of the value for editing. When I give the inputs left and/or right padding the text boxes become too long. Why is this happening? How can I get accurate positioning and padding at the same time?

[image: distorted absolute positions]

html

```
<div id="container">

<input type="text" class="no-padding" style="top:10%; left:05%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="1000">
<input type="text" class="no-padding" style="top:10%; left:35%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="2000">
<input type="text" class="no-padding" style="top:10%; left:65%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="3000">

<input type="text" class="padding" style="top:30%; left:05%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="1000">
<input type="text" class="padding" style="top:30%; left:35%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="2000">
<input type="text" class="padding" style="top:30%; left:65%; width:29%; height:10%;" value="3000">

</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid dimgray;
    position: relative;
}

input {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(105, 105, 105, 1);
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.padding {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcH3H/)

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you need absolute positions? Since you widths are fixed, no wonder: any padding increases a div's width. Plus, you're mixing percentages and pixels, and thus you're asking for trouble. Why not use Bootstrap grid system ?

Comment: I need the absolute positions because the inputs overlay a background image and have arbitrary positions that I don't control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width change is because you are specifying a width in the inline styles (29%, which I assume is an attempt to hack your way into getting all three inputs to take up 1/3 of the width including their padding), but the width of an input is the width of "writable space".  Adding padding (aka the space in between the text and the border) will therefore increase the width.

As has been mentioned, mixing percentages and pixel sizes is generally a terrible idea.

BUT, if you just have to have your 4px left and right padding, then add

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;   /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

to your Input css.

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL32d/)

Comment: The styles are inline because they are computed and applied with JavaScript. I can look into padding with percents, but narrow and wide text boxes need to have the same padding. The box-sizing rule is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into box-sizing.

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Some elements have their widths calculated as width + border width + padding width, others include the padding within the overall width.

Note that this can also be browser-specific, so a normalize stylesheet may also help.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hcH3H/1/